# WSO2 ESB URL Rewrite has no effect?

Tags: url-rewriting, wso2, wso2-esb

I'm trying to modify an URL with a URLrewrite mediator but it seems to has no effect.

I want to replace the word "user1" to "customer1", and then send the request to an endpoint

In my proxy i recieve this URL:

"/services/myproxy/user1"

And i have to rewrite it to:

"/services/myproxy/customer1" (and then to endpont: "http://endpoint.com/customer1").

The URLRewrite mediator is:

```
<rewrite xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <rewriterule>
      <action value="customer1" regex="user1" type="replace" fragment="path"/>
   </rewriterule>
</rewrite>
```

but at the end the proxy sends the URL request with "user1" instead of "customer1"!!

whats wrong in my config?? I don't see any errors in my log!!

thanks!!!

Comment: Can you share your complete sequence?

Answer (score 0):

Following syntax is working perfect for me. What is the version of ESB you are working?

```
<rewrite>
         <rewriterule>
            <action value="customer1" regex="user1" type="replace" fragment="path"/>
         </rewriterule>
      </rewrite>
      <send/>
```

Comment: I'm using 4.7.0 and also with 4.6.0. Maybe I need to modify the endpoint? or to put a send mediator with a specific config?

Comment: I mean the syntax above works, but is not applied when the proxy sends the request to the endpoint.

Comment: what do you mean by "syntax above works, but is not applied when the proxy sends the request to the endpoint"? This is contradicting. If the above syntax works, then the message should be routed to correct endpoint. you can test this simply with this example. http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Sample+450%3A+Introduction+to+the+URL+Rewrite+Mediator

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar problem. In my case, I missed to set the `outProperty` back into `REST_URL_POSTFIX` after rewriting the url. Hope this can help someone having same problem in the future.

```
<sequence>
  <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" expression="get-property('axis2','REST_URL_POSTFIX')"/>
  <rewrite inProperty="REST_URL_POSTFIX" outProperty="REST_URL_POSTFIX">
    <rewriterule>
      <action fragment="path" type="replace" regex="^/soap/sms" value="/sms" />
    </rewriterule>
  </rewrite>
  
  <property name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2" expression="get-property('REST_URL_POSTFIX')"/>
  ^^ Make sure to set this back ^^
</sequence>
```